# Changing wpf elements/controls from another class or static method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, data-binding

I have a MainWindow that contains a text-block [statusTextblock] which has binding to a string [StatusText]. StatusTextblock needs to display combobox results from another window. I pass this data back to mainwindow when it changes in the other window and I've made a static method to change the string when this happens.

However, the staticness of all this leaves me unable to change my textbox element at any point to the new value of StatusText.

I thought about work arounds to bring the changes about when the user returned to Mainwindow but I've not succeeded. I tried the activate and uielement gotfocus event handler (i feel the 2nd one is still a possible fix).

Mainwindow also happens to be always open if that matters. I also prefer doing things in code than xaml, but would be grateful for any help.

Any ideas?

MainWindow xaml, then program entry method, then static event to change statusText

```
<TextBlock Margin="190,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="StatusTextBlock" Text= {Binding}" ></TextBlock>

public MainWindow() //Obviously more went here, but it's not relevent
    {
        StatusTextBlock.DataContext = statusText;
    }

static public void changeStatusText(string status)
    {
        statusText = status;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem becomes simpler to solve when you try to implement the application using MVVM pattern.

1. Define a view model class which has a string property StatusText:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   { 
     private string _statusText;

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     public string StatusText
     {
       get
       {
           return _statusText;
       }

       set
       {
           if (value == _statusText)
               return;

           _statusText = value;

           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusText"));
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Set the DataContext of the MainWindow to an instance of the MainViewModel:

   ```
   public MainWindow  //Obviously more went here, but it's not relevant
   {  
      private static MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

      public MainWindow() 
      { 
         this.DataContext = _mainViewModel;
      }

      static public void ChangeStatusText(string status)
      { 
        _mainViewModel.StatusText = status;
      }
    }
   ```
3. Set the data binding to the view model:

   ```
    <TextBlock Margin="190,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="StatusTextBlock" Text="{Binding StatusText}" ></TextBlock>
   ```

Comment: Excellent, i finally have enough reputation to upvote that, done.

Comment: using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;  of course